# How to create multiple tree view in single treeview in winforms?

Tags: c#, treeview

[image]

hi buddy! I want to create multiple treeviews in single treeview as it is shown in above figure. i can create only one treeview but cannot create another one with no links.

can anyone wake me up from this nightmare???

Comment: do you mean multiple levels of tree nodes like VS solution explorer?

Comment: almost yes, but i don't need the line which connect the sibling node.

Comment: Do you basically want to get rid of the top most parent node of the tree view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
treeView1.BeginUpdate();
treeView1.ShowRootLines = false;
treeView1.ShowLines = false;
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Parent");
treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Child 1");
treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Child 2");
treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("Grandchild");
treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Great Grandchild");
treeView1.EndUpdate();
```

just copied and edited the example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx)